# QGIS: put vector values into separate layers?

Tags: qgis

QGIS 1.8.0 Mac: I've got a polygon shape file with values 1-5 in it i.e. contours. How do I get the polygons for value 5 into one layer, 4 into another... so I can assign each a colour and see them?

Comment: ? You want to split your layer or you want to apply a classified coloration?

Comment: it's supposed to be a polygon hazard map with 5 values 1-5; I want to end up with each polygon value showing a distinct colour fill. One layer or 5 is OK, it's just that at the moment I can't see anything at all.

Comment: that is 1-2 being one colour, 2-3 being a 2nd etc.

Comment: note also that it isn't a contour map where 1 must be adjacent to 2; there can be an area level 5 surrounded by level 1.

Comment: I also note that QGIS doesn't show anything when the shapefile is imported, it just shows that it's a polygon layer. I found a show discrete values window that told me the values are 1-5, but that's all. If I could see the shapes, I could use them...

Comment: I've found how ArcView handles it: 1. In ArcView, click the Theme menu; then click Edit Legend. The Legend Editor window will appear.
2. Click on the Legend Type field in the Legend Editor.
3. Choose Unique Value in the Legend Type dropdown menu.
4. Click on the Values Field in the Legend Editor.
5. Choose the ELEV_CLASS field in the Values Field dropdown menu.
6. Click Apply.

Comment: See http://hub.qgis.org/issues/7416 for attempts to solve the problem.

Comment: Problem partly solved - see link above. I converted vector files as described & created a new project with them. But, now my geotiff air photo refuses to show :-(

Comment: because the tfw file has to be converted to UTM 18N values, of course !

Comment: Hey, if you don't mind then please write an answer for your question and accept it. This will help other people looking for help!

Comment: done - I just wanted to be sure I had it 100% right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. start new project (to avoid CRS confusion)
2. load vector
3. under layer properties, style, choose graduated from drop-down list
4. click classify
5. adjust colours and ranges as you wish
6. OK

see above & link to hub.qgis.org for further details if confused.